# Spring using Anonymous Authentication Provider to use Guest User

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring framework with Security in my web application. I have a Guest user and its privileges in my db but I can't implement AnonymousAuthenticationFilter and AnonymousAuthenticationProvider to use that user. Here is my appSecurity configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
        p:loginFormUrl="/login" p:useForward="false" p:forceHttps="false" />

    <bean id="successHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        p:defaultTargetUrl="/" />

    <bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:defaultFailureUrl="/login?error=true" p:useForward="false" />

    <bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
        class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security.CustomAccessDeniedHandler">
        <property name="accessDeniedUrl" value="/accessDenied" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.service.UserServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="tokenBasedRememberMeServices"
        class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security.CustomRememberMeServices">
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
        <property name="key" value="abcdef123456" />
        <property name="parameter" value="remember" />
        <property name="cookieName" value="_ab_memo" />
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security.AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="postOnly" value="true" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
        <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="tokenBasedRememberMeServices" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="anonymousAuthProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="rememberMeAuthProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="anonymousAuthProvider" class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security.CustomAnonymousAuthProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <property name="key" value="foobar" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="rememberMeAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="key" value="xy1245aazpo98qwe" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security.UserAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <property name='securityContextRepository'>
            <bean
                class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
                <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='false' />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler" />

    <bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
                <ref bean="tokenBasedRememberMeServices"/> 
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean name="rememberMeAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="tokenBasedRememberMeServices" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="anonymousProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="key" value="foobar" />
        <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,PRIV_ANONYMOUS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
        <property name="rolePrefix" value="PRIV_"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security.CustomAccessDecisionManager">
        <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false" />
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityMetadataSource" class="com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security.CustomFilterInvocationDefinitionSource"/>

    <bean id="filterInvocationInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
        <property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="securityMetadataSource" />
        <property name="rejectPublicInvocations" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,
                logoutFilter,
                authenticationProcessingFilter,
                rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,
                anonymousProcessingFilter,
                exceptionTranslationFilter,
                filterInvocationInterceptor" />
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And here is my Custom Anonymous Authentication Provider:

```
package com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.security;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

import com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.model.GuiUser;
import com.asosyalbebe.springtest.gui.user.service.UserService;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CustomAnonymousAuthProvider extends AnonymousAuthenticationProvider {
    private UserService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        GuiUser user = userDetailsService.getGuestUser();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "pwd", user.getAuthorities());
        result.setDetails(user);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> class1) {
        return true;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsService(UserService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

I think the `authenticate` method in `CustomAnonymousAuthProvider` is never executed. What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `AuthenticationManager`'s perspective, the `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` which is created by then filter is already authenticated (the `isAuthenticated` property is `true`), so it doesn't try to authenticate it. Hence your provider is not called.

The simplest option would be to customize the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` to use the authorities from your database directly.